# Jquery date picker not working with Google Map InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps, jquery-ui-datepicker

Jquery ui datepicker is working outside the map but in the map the jquery ui datepicker not working.

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Code:

```
var html = "<table width='250px' height='300px'>" +
                 "...." +
                 "<tr><td>Url:...." +
                 "<tr><td>Date:</td> <td><input type='text' id='datepicker'/> </td> </tr>" +               
                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr></table>";

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });
```

I can save all the form information from the map. But the datepicker is not working inside the map.

And the event listener i am using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Anyone have any idea?

image: http://postimg.org/image/oe40y960z/

Answer (score 1):

use the `domready`-event of the `infowindow` to create the datepicker.

Before the `domready`-event the table hasn't been injected into the document and `#datepicker` may not be accessed by jQuery.

Another option: apply the datepicker directly before you set the content:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: $(html).find('#datepicker').datepicker().end()[0]
});
```

Note: when the UI will be covered by the map set the zIndex:

```
#ui-datepicker-div{z-index:1000 !important}
```

Comment: thank you very much.
What i have done from your suggestion ,`code`
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: $(html).find('#datepicker').datepicker().end()[0]
    });`code`
and also added the css.
It is perfect now.

Comment: Papps, you should mark Dr. Molle's answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass datepicker in domready

Below is the code

```
 infowindow.addListener('domready', function() {
        $('.datepicker').fdatepicker({
            pickTime: true,
        });
    });
```