# Jquery UI Datepicker Not Working Inside Google Map Infowindow

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, datepicker, coffeescript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having an issue with the jQuery UI Datepicker when it is placed inside an Google Map Infowindow.

We are building an itinerary manager with multiple destinations. Each destination has a arrival and departure date, each with a datepicker. There are two places you can set these dates, inside the 'itinerary' div at the bottom of the page and inside the InfoWindow on a Google Map. The datepickers are working fine in the intinerary, but the calendars do not display inside the Google Map infowindow.

The Infowindows are created and updated dynamically using the two methods below:

```
  #opens the infowindow associated with destination
  openInfowindow: (destination, map) =>
    info_content = @_generateInfowindowHTML(destination)

    if not @infowindow #infowindow not defined
      @infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
        content: info_content
    else #infowindow already created
      @infowindow.setContent(info_content)

    @infowindow.open(map, destination.marker)

  #produces the HTML content for the infowindow association with destination
  _generateInfowindowHTML: (destination) =>
    iw = $('#infowindow-template').clone(true).removeClass('hidden').removeAttr('id')
    iw.find('h5').text(destination.formatted_address) #infowindow header, formatted address
    iw.find('.infowindow-content').attr('data-destination-uid', destination.uid)
    iw.find('.infowindow-content').attr('id', 'infowindow-uid-' + destination.uid)

    #Setting date pickers for destinations
    #NOTE: All datepickers need unique ids
    iw.find('.destination-arrival-date-picker').attr('id', 'infowindow-destination-arrival-datepicker-uid-' + destination.uid)
    iw.find('.destination-arrival-date-picker').datepicker
      autosize: true
      dateFormat: "M d, yy"
      onSelect: (date, input) ->
        console.log 'selected arrival date!'

    iw.find('.destination-departure-date-picker').attr('id', 'infowindow-destination-departure-datepicker-uid-' + destination.uid)
    iw.find('.destination-departure-date-picker').datepicker
      autosize: true
      dateFormat: "M d, yy"
      onSelect: (date, input) ->
        console.log 'selected departure!'


    return  iw.html()
```

The HTML in question:

```
<!-- Info window template -->
<div id="infowindow-template" class="hidden">
  <div class="infowindow-content" data-destination-uid="">
    <h5>Location Name</h5>
    <div class="block info-date-container link-text">
      <div class="add-destination-date">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i> <span>Add Dates</span>
      </div>
      <div class="edit-destination-date-div hidden inline-block">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o fa-fw in-form-icon"></i>
        <%= text_field_tag '', nil, :class => 'date-picker destination-date-picker destination-arrival-date-picker',
                            :placeholder => 'Arrival Date' %>

        <i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o fa-fw in-form-icon"></i>
        <%= text_field_tag '', nil, :class => 'date-picker destination-date-picker destination-departure-date-picker',
                            :placeholder => 'Departure Date' %>
        <i class="fa fa-check confirm-destination-dates icon--confirm"
             data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Confirm Dates"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="destination-date-wrapper hidden inline-block">
        <span class="destination-arrival-date"> ? </span>
        <span> to </span>
        <span class="destination-departure-date"> ? </span>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil edit-destination-date" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="below" title="Change Dates"></i>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End Info Date Container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Our Investigation So Far:**

- We verified each datepicker input has a unique DOM ID
- The 'hasDatePicker' class is dynamically added to the correct input field
- The issue is not that the datepicker is hidden behind the map. We know this because chrome inspector says the position of the datepicker has not been set
- We added a test button inside the infowindow and tried to manually initialize the datepicker (e.g. `$('#datepicker-id').datepicker()`), but this did not work.
- It looks like the issue in all the other similar threads was that the datepicker was being initialized before the datepicker was ever in the DOM, but based on my above investigation we do not think that is the case for us.

Similar threads:

1. [Jquery date picker not working with Google Map InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661703/jquery-date-picker-not-working-with-google-map-infowindow)
2. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-not-seem-to-work-inside-infowindow-from-a-google-map-v3-marker

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `_generateInfowindowHTML()` you must return `iw[0]` instead of `iw.html()` . When you return the html it's just a string, you will lose all the functionality that has been added to the element and it's  children.